# Does the JOIN really duplicate data on the level of response from the database?

Tags: postgresql, join

As an example, let's take PostgreSQL and say we have two tables with one to many relationship. Making the INNER JOIN produces "duplicates" from the first table. Are those duplicated rows really returning as copies of the same data from the database on the level of database connection, or are they just representation of the data on the client to fit that data into a table?

Comment: What is the difference between a duplicate and a representation?

Comment: One way is when data duplicated (copied) on the server and passed to the client, another is when data passed to the client has no actual copies, but duplicated on the client side only to fit that data into a table format.

Comment: The "duplication" takes part on the server, when the result set is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of confusion in the responses I'm seeing on here so far, but jjanes is correct. Your original question was:

> Does the JOIN really duplicate data on the level of response from the database?

Yes, in a one-to-many (or many-to-many) relationship, a `JOIN` will result in the data being duplicated down the rows on the opposite side of the many (in a many-to-many relationship this would cause duplication on both sides).

From a logical perspective, this means the data is structured with duplicates when it's coming from the database layer, before it's even reached the client side. The client side is **not** doing the duplication.

From a physical perspective, the data is truly duplicated (typically sitting in Memory for the duration of the query execution). That means if there was a single character column that took up 1 byte of data in the native table, then if it was duplicated 5 times from the `JOIN`, the duplication would cause 5 physical bytes of data to exist. This would be 5 bytes of data transferred across the network, and returned to the client side. Do note, this isn't duplicating the data in the original base table on Disk though. It is a temporary duplication that typically resides in Memory.

Comment: *Do note, this isn't duplicating the data in the original base table on Disk though. It is a temporary duplication that typically resides in Memory* this is the statement that my answer is based on.  Now that I'm reading all the answers and the question again I'm am confused what the OP is asking

Comment: @ErgestBasha agreed that's it's unclear exactly what's being asked. Hopefully my answer is a little more explicit to clarify in all regards.

Comment: Yeah it is more clear than mine and since it is more detailed I will delete my answer to not cause confusions to future readers. +1

Answer (score 1):

Let's try it and see.

```
strace -s 10000 psql -c "select * from repeat('a',200) cross join generate_series(1,10) f(i)"
```

Yep, the data is really duplicated.  There are a lot more than 200 a's there in the recvfrom() call.